# Why aren't empty strings filtered out of this Java stream?

Tags: java, java-stream, numberformatexception

I have a stream operation (Java 8) that is meant to parse a bunch of strings into doubles and take a sum.  Some of the strings are empty, but I don't believe any are null. I've added a `filter` operation to filter the empty ones out before they reach `Double.parseDouble()` where they might cause an error, but the filter doesn't seem to work.

My code:

```
double myTotal= myObjectList.stream()
    .map(myObject::getAmount)
    .peek( s -> System.out.println("before filter: " + s) )
    .filter( s -> !s.isEmpty() )
    .peek( s -> System.out.println("after filter: " + s) )
    .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
    .reduce(0D,Double::sum);
```

This is in a JSP, and the JSP fails to compile.  According to the error page, the exception occurs in the last line (`.reduce(0D,Double::sum);`), but the "root cause" is a "`java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String`" -- `Double.parseDouble()` is encountering empty strings.

I have tried several permutations of the `filter` operation, including some that checked for null and some that checked `!s.equals("")` and the like.  I added the `peek` operations for debugging and it is clear that an empty string is being printed both *before* and *after* the `filter` line.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to filter out values that can't be parsed to doubles?

Comment: What are you returning from `myObject::getAmount` ?

Comment: a String which can be empty but won't be null

Comment: As other user mentioned, what is your def of an `empty` string. Are those empty as in `""` or they are empty as in `"    "`?

Comment: Perhaps try adding `.filter( s -> s.matches("-?\\d+([.]\\d+)?"))` after the `empty` filter so that _only_ numbers get through?

Comment: @EmAe It's not my definition, it's whatever causes Double.parseDouble to throw a NumberFormatException with the comment "empty string".  You may have put your finger on the problem, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String with white spaces, technically not empty, cause an exception to be raised with the message "empty string". As another poster pointed out, the solution is to trim the input string first.

This confusion is the result of an unfortunate documentation bug in `sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString` which is indirectly called by `Double.parseDouble`. Although the semantics of [`String#empty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) is

> Returns `true` if, and only if, `length()` is 0.

the implementation of `readJavaFormatString` actually *trims* the input string *first*, then computes the length, and throws the `NumberFormatException` with the (very misleading) message "empty string":

```
in = in.trim(); // don't fool around with white space.
                // throws NullPointerException if null 
int len = in.length();
if ( len == 0 ) {
    throw new NumberFormatException("empty String");
}
```

This can be readily observed by executing:

```
Double.parseDouble("   ");
```

Comment: This is the explanation that I needed.  I solved my problem by adding a `map(String::trim)` step before the filter.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it are white spaces, you can `trim()` the string first and then check if it's empty, to also remove the whitespace Strings like:

```
double myTotal= myObjectList.stream()
            .map(myObject::getAmount)
            .peek( s -> System.out.println("before filter: " + s) )
            .filter( s ->  !s.trim().isEmpty() )
            .peek( s -> System.out.println("after filter: " + s) )
            .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
            .reduce(0D,Double::sum);
```

If you use java 11 you can use `String.isBlank()` in your filter instead of isEmpty(). `isEmpty()` looks at the lenght of the string. isBlank looks for whitespaces.

Comment: Note that `isBlank()` is Java11+.

Comment: ... and that OP specifically said "*Java 8*".

Comment: @Willem you're on the right track, it does seem that my problem was a string full of whitespace.  Want to edit this answer?

Comment: @user85421: `Predicate.not(…)` requires Java 11. But generally, keeping the result of `trim()` is a good idea.

Comment: isBlank() actually evaluates both whether the string is empty or if it contains only white space codepoints.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache's ***StringUtils.isNotBlank*** function as well.It will take care of both Null and Empty strings.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank(java.lang.CharSequence)

```
double myTotal= Stream.of("","10.00","20.22","  ")
                //.map(myObject::getAmount)
                .peek( s -> System.out.println("before filter: " + s) )
                .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                .peek( s -> System.out.println("after filter: " + s) )
                .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                .reduce(0D,Double::sum);
```

**Output:**

before filter:

before filter: 10.00

after filter: 10.00

before filter: 20.22

after filter: 20.22

before filter:

30.22